# Why are there 3 nodes in a default Google Kubernetes Engine cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

A default Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster

```
gcloud container clusters create [CLUSTER_NAME] \
--zone [COMPUTE_ZONE]
```

starts with 3 nodes. What's the idea behind that? Shouldn't 2 nodes in the same zone be sufficient for high availability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes uses [etcd](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd) for state. Etcd uses [Raft](https://raft.github.io/) for consensus to achieve high availability properties.

When using a consensus protocol like Raft, you need *majority* in voting. Using 3 nodes you need 2 of 3 nodes to respond for availability. Using 2 nodes, you can not get majority with only 1 of 2 nodes, so you need both 2 nodes to be available.

Comment: thanks, that sounds reasonable. At the same time I know that one can also setup a Kubernetes system with only one or two nodes. What limitations would one have then? Which functions exactly would be limited when one runs with less than 3 nodes?

Comment: with one or two nodes, you can not tolerate that one is down, so no _high availability_ but it will work as long as all nodes is responding. But you can not e.g. upgrade nodes or cluster without downtime.

Comment: Thank you, my comment wasn't very precise. I am still new to Kubernetes and don't know, which of its functions require consensus. As this might a more comprehensive topic, I opened a new question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59073769/practical-consequences-of-missing-consensus-on-a-kubernetes-cluster